# Is there a way to get generic constraints take in an enum in swift? Or is there a better way to reduce code?

Tags: swift, enums, protocols, code-duplication

What I want to do is somewhat complicated, pardon all the variable names.

Currently I have been to doing something like

```
enum Foo {
    enum Bar {
        case prop11
        case prop12
        case prop13
        // etc
    }

    enum Baz {
        case prop21
        case prop22
        case prop23
        // etc
    }
}

protocol Fum1 {
    var zot: Foo.Bar { get set }
}

protocol Fum2 {
    var zot: Foo.Baz { get set }
}

struct Grunt1: Fum1 {
    // code
}

struct Grunt2: Fum2 {
    // code
}
```

This is causing me to duplicate a LOT of code though. Because the same functions can (for the most part) be run on either `Grunt1` or `Grunt2`, and I keep having to specify with something like this

```
protocol Bletch {
    func doSomething(to grunt: Grunt1)
    func doSomething(to grunt: Grunt2)
}
```

But the implementations are the same for both functions. This is quite frustrating. I'd like to do something like

```
protocol Fum {
    associatedType Thud

    var zot: Thud { get set }
}

struct Grunt<T: Foo>: Fum {
    typealias Thud = T
}
```

This would then let me do something like

```
let grunt1 = Grunt<Foo.Bar>(zot: .prop11) //Autocompletes to .prop11, .prop12, .prop13

let grunt2 = Grunt<Foo.Baz>(zot: .prop23) //Autocompletes to .prop23, .prop22, .prop23
```

Then I could do something like

```
protocol Bletch {
    func doSomething(to grunt: Fum) // or (any Fum), whichever doesn't throw errors.
}
```

But this doesn't work, Is there a different way of getting the result I'm after? I'm just trying to reduce duplicate code.

Comment: hard to tell what you're trying to accomplsh but using generics at this level is usually a misdirection

Comment: Does `doSomething` access the `zot` property at any point? If it does, then the two `doSomething` overloads in `Bletch` don't have "the same implementations", do they? One works with `prop11`, `prop12` and `prop13`, and the other works with `prop21`, `prop22` and `prop23`.

Comment: The zot property is used, but it's used in the same way for all propXX. But at the same time, there is a necessary distinction between Bar and Baz... It's complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of what you describe already works except `<T: Foo>` since `Foo` is not a protocol.

Instead of making `Foo.Bar` and `Foo.Baz` nested types, you can make `Foo` a protocol and let both `Bar` and `Baz` adopt the protocol. (why are they nested types anyways?):

```swift
protocol Foo {}

enum Bar : Foo { /* cases */ }
enum Baz : Foo { /* cases */ }
```

---

If that's not an option, you can also extend `Foo.Bar` and `Foo.Baz` and let them both adopt to a common protocol:

```swift
protocol FooProtocol {}

extension Foo.Bar : FooProtocol {}
extension Foo.Baz : FooProtocol {}
```

Now you just need to constraint your generic `T` on `Grunt` to be a `FooProtocol` instead of `Foo`:

```swift
struct Grunt<T: FooProtocol>: Fum {
    typealias Thud = T
    var zot: Thud
}
```

Comment: This might do what I'm wanting... would you be willing to expand this and give an example of the extension idea?

Comment: @TinyTim I have added more detail in the answer. Hope this help.

Comment: This second solution does exactly what I needed! Thank you!